# Split an integer into digits (Hundreds, tens, units) and store in ARRAYS

Tags: arrays, vba, split, factorial, digits

I am working on some code that will compute very large factorial products that are much too large to fit into a Long-integer. I am to use 2 arrays, F() and C(). F is for the multiplication products and to store the units, C() is for the "carries", which will be added later. So the units are stored in F(I), for instance, C(I+1) holds the tens, C(I+2) holds the hundreds. Later you will add C(I) + F(I).

```
Dim F(0 To 30) As Single, C(0 To 30) As Single, sum As Single
Dim length As Single, split1 As Single, split2 As Single
Dim nexttwo As String, mult As String
```

---

```
Sub LargeFactCalc()
    F(1) = 1
    N = InputBox("Enter the number you would like to factorialize: ")
    For J = 2 To N
        For I = 1 To 30
            mult = J * F(I)
            Call split
        Next I
        sum = C(I) + F(I)
        C(I + 1) = 0
        C(I + 2) = 0
    Next J

Print #1, F(I)
Close #1
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub split()
    Select Case Len(mult)
    Case 1
        F(I) = mult 'UNITS
    Case 2
        C(I + 1) = Left(mult, 1) 'Tens
        F(I) = Right(mult, 1) 'Units
    Case 3
        C(I + 2) = Left(mult, 1) 'Hundreds
        C(I+1) = 'Tens should go here but I don't 
                 'know how to seperate the middle number
        F(I) = Right(mult, 1) 'Units
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is either the `Mid` function, which returns a number of character starting at a specific character, or a combination or `Right` and `Left` functions.

Try either :

```
C(I + 1) = Mid(mult, 2, 1)  'Returns 1 character starting from the 2nd character of mult
```

or :

```
C(I + 1) = Left(Right(mult, 2), 1) 'Returns the left-most character, 
                                   'of the 2 right-most characters
```

Comment: Thank you Bernard. Now it goes through without error, so hopefully it will work. I just have to write the rest of the main program.

Answer (score 0):

Format is Microsoft ACCESS 2010.

I have this in a form to split my AMOUNT field into hundreds, tens & units and enter these into individual fields on the same form called H, T & U.
I have made the hundreds H show all numbers if it larger that 999. i.e. if the result is 1234 it will show 12 in H 3 in T and 4 in U.
This is done by counting the length in the AMOUNT field. It is simple, short and sweet with no error catching yet.

Code is below.

Private Sub AMOUNT_AfterUpdate()

Dim LenAmt As String

LenAmt = Len(AMOUNT)

H = Mid(Right(AMOUNT, LenAmt), 1, LenAmt - 2)

T = Mid(Right(AMOUNT, 2), 1, 1)

U = Mid(Right(AMOUNT, 1), 1, 1)

Me.Refresh

End Sub